# SELECT MAX and MIN from COUNT - MySQL

Tags: mysql, count, max, min

i have employees with officecode table, and i want to show officecode **ONLY** with **max** and **min** employees ,

this is the table

```
+----------------+------------+
| employeenumber | officecode |
+----------------+------------+
|           1002 | 1          |
|           1056 | 4          |
|           1076 | 1          |
|           1143 | 7          |
|           1165 | 1          |
|           1166 | 6          |
            ....   .
            ....   .
+----------------+------------+
```

and this is what **i want to get**:

```
+------------+----------+
| officecode | empCount |
+------------+----------+
|           1|         6|
|           7|         2|
+------------+----------+
```

this is my method :

**First** i COUNT and GROUP them

**then** SELECT MAX from it and UNION it with SELECT MIN

**but** the SELECT MIN return wrong officecode

this is my code :

```
SELECT officecode, MAX(empcount) AS 'empcount'
FROM
    (
    SELECT officecode, count(*) AS 'empCount' 
    FROM employees 
    GROUP BY officecode
    )
AS temp

UNION

    SELECT officecode, MIN(empcount) AS 'empcount'
FROM
    (
    SELECT officecode, count(*) AS 'empCount' 
    FROM employees 
    GROUP BY officecode
    )
AS temp2
```

the `AS tmp` must be there unless it will return error

it returned :

```
+------------+----------+
| officecode | empCount |
+------------+----------+
|           1|         6|
|           1|         2|
+------------+----------+
```

anyone knwo where i'm wrong?
or maybe you have another method because my method look so loooooong, thx

Comment: why u are doing union your first query should be doing the job `select officecode, count(*) AS 'empCount' FROM employees GROUP BY officecode`

Comment: you should try this: `SELECT MIN(officecode) AS Minofficecode, MAX(officecode) AS Maxofficecode FROM employees;`

Comment: i think you get my question wrong, i mean the employee have his office code, and i want to count the office number of employee, and what i want to get in the end is to show office with most and least number of employee working in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(
    SELECT officecode, count(*) AS empCount 
    FROM employees 
    GROUP BY officecode 
    ORDER BY empCount ASC 
    LIMIT 1
) 
UNION ALL
(
    SELECT officecode, count(*) AS empCount 
    FROM employees 
    GROUP BY officecode 
    ORDER BY empCount DESC 
    LIMIT 1
)
```

Comment: yeah, i just figure this out from the previous answer, combination of ORDER BY with LIMIT, nice thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simple try this

```
SELECT officecode,MAX(empcount),MIN(empcount) count(*) AS 'empCount' FROM employees GROUP BY officecode
```

Comment: i already used that to get all the office code with the employees number, but i want to get office with max and min value

Comment: i try this but it seems error, it don't recognise 'empCount' field list

Answer (score 0):

***you need this:***

```
SELECT *
FROM
((SELECT ACTION, COUNT(ACTION) FROM t1
GROUP BY ACTION
ORDER BY ACTION DESC
LIMIT 1)
UNION 
(SELECT ACTION, COUNT(ACTION) FROM t1
GROUP BY ACTION
ORDER BY ACTION ASC
LIMIT 1))t
```

***check this sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7116b5/1***

Comment: nice, your answer is right the answer i choose has same method but more short, but thank you for your response

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
SELECT officecode, MAX( empCount ) AS  'empCount'
FROM 
    (
    SELECT officecode, COUNT( * ) AS  'empCount'
    FROM employees 
    GROUP BY officecode ORDER BY empCount DESC 
    ) 
AS temp
UNION
SELECT officecode, MIN( empCount ) AS  'empCount'
FROM 
    (
    SELECT officecode, COUNT( * ) AS  'empCount'
    FROM employees 
    GROUP BY officecode ORDER BY empCount ASC 
    )
AS temp2
```

Comment: Even if it is an acceptable solution for OP, it should be noted that this uses an undocumented side effect of how MySQL implements aggregating, and is not guaranteed to work.

Comment: But without aggregation is it possible to easily achieve..? @Vatev

Comment: yeah this query returned the result i want, but the query become more looong, anyway thanks

Comment: Yeah.. Just added an orderby :)